# Updating Varying Columns with SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. One with the format as follows:

```
Id | FieldName | Value
0  | field1    | 0
1  | field2    | 0
2  | field3    | 0
```

The second with the following format:

```
Id | field1 | field2 | field3
0  |   1    |   1    |   1
1  |   1    |   1    |   1
2  |   1    |   1    |   1
```

I need to update the second table so that the 1's are changed to 0's where the fieldname column value matches the column value in the second table. So the final table should look like this:

```
Id | field1 | field2 | field3
0  |   0    |   1    |   1
1  |   1    |   0    |   1
2  |   1    |   1    |   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
Select a.id,
Case when (fieldName='field1' and field1=1) then value else field1 end as field1,
Case when (fieldName='field2' and field2=1) then value else field2 end as field2,
Case when (fieldName='field3' and field3=1) then value else field3 end as field3
from 
table2 a
inner join
table1 b 
on a.id=b.id
```

Thanks:-)

Comment: Thank you! That helps me think a little more clearly about the problem.